# EF Core Bulk Insert is not updating the expected database generated IDs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, efcore.bulkextensions

I'm using the [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) lib version 6.7.0 and Entity Framework Core v6.0.13, trying to reproduce the following behaviour explained in the docs:

```csharp
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    context.BulkInsert(entities, new BulkConfig { SetOutputIdentity = true });

    foreach (var entity in entities) 
    {
        foreach (var subEntity in entity.ItemHistories) 
        {
            subEntity.ItemId = entity.ItemId; // sets FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
        }

        subEntities.AddRange(entity.ItemHistories);
    }

    context.BulkInsert(subEntities);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

The `entity.ItemId` is supposed to be updated with the PK generated by the database.

I couldn't reproduce it with the following code, the result is always: `[ENTITY ID]: 0`

```csharp
using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var entities = entitiesEnumerable.ToList();

    foreach (var e in entities)
    {
        e.Id = default;
    }

    var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig
    {
        SetOutputIdentity = true
    };

    await dbContext.BulkInsertAsync(entities, bulkConfig);

    foreach (var e in entities)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning($"[ENTITY ID]: {e.Id}");
    }

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

My entity has the following attribute as PK and the underlying database is SQL Server:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public long Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `transaction.Commit();` before last foreach loop.
For other Q, you can make and issue on the Git repo.